# Only last message is displayed when ApexPages.addMessage is used

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

In my VisualForce page there are 2 buttons.
Each button handler performs an action and add an information message to the page using

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, message));
```

The page is something like this :

```
<apex:pageBlock id="Test1" mode="edit">

<apex:pageMessages />

<apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:commandButton action="{!action1}" reRender="Test1" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!action2}" reRender="Test1" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

In each of the `action1` and `action2` methods, after doing some operation a message is added using

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, message));
```

But I always get the last message added in the `<apex:pageMessages />` section.

Why can not I see both the messages ?

Comment: If the text of both messages is the same I think only one message will appear. You will also need to re-render the part of the page with the apex:pageMessages in it.

Answer (score 3):

Each transaction clears the message queue, so if you have two buttons, clicking one then the other clears the first message. You can show multiple messages in an `apex:pageMessaages` area, but they must all come from the same transaction. Also, duplicate messages may be discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sfdcfox .  Can you elaborate a bit on what exactly defines a transaction because I have tried in a test method to call action1() and action2() consecutively and then when I called ApexPages.getMessages() , both the messages were there

Comment: Calling action1() and action2() in a test method is considered a single transaction. But calling action1() on a button click is a separate transaction than calling action2() on another button click.

Comment: Is there any way to call action1() and action2() in two separate transactions in test class

Comment: @AnindyaHalder Not directly. You could use `ApexPages.getMessages().clear()` to reset the messages, though.

Comment: Why can't you test those two methods in two test methods so it will be in different transactions.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have tried that seeing your post but it does not work